# Getting the unicode value of the first character in a string

Tags: java, methods, unicode, logic, getter

I am basically being asked to take the Unicode value of a string, multiply it by 10% and add whatever level the object currently has. It's frustrating because as it turns out I have the logic down including the code yet I still get an error that says: expected:<0> but was:<8>. Any suggestions, maybe it's just a slight nuance I have to make in the logic, although I'm fairly certain it's right. **Take note of the getLevel method because that's where the error is**

```
public class PouchCreature implements Battleable {

private String name;
private int strength;
private int levelUps;
private int victoriesSinceLevelUp;

/**
 * Standard constructor.  levelUps and victoriesSinceLevelUp start at 0.
 * 
 * @param nameIn desired name for this PouchCreature
 * @param strengthIn starting strength for this PouchCreature
 */
public PouchCreature(String nameIn, int strengthIn) {
    this.name = nameIn;
    this.strength = strengthIn;
    this.levelUps = 0;
    this.victoriesSinceLevelUp = 0;
}


/**
 * Copy constructor.  
 * 
 * @param other reference to the existing object which is the basis of the new one
 */
public PouchCreature(PouchCreature other) {
    this.name=other.name;
    this.strength=other.strength;
    this.levelUps=other.levelUps;
    this.victoriesSinceLevelUp=other.victoriesSinceLevelUp;
}


/**
 * Getter for skill level of the PouchCreature, which is based on the
 * first character of its name and the number of levelUps it has.
 * Specifically, the UNICODE value of the first character in its name
 * taken %10 plus the levelUps.
 * 
 * @return skill level of the PouchCreature
 */
public int getLevel() {
    int value = (int)((int)(getName().charAt(0)) * 0.1);
    return value + this.levelUps;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said you're supposed to *increase* the value by 10%. What you're actually doing, though, is *reducing* it 90% by taking just 10% of it (and then truncating that to an `int`). `67.0 * 0.1 = 6.7`, which when truncated to an `int` is `6`.

Change the `0.1` to `1.1` to *increase* it by 10%:

```
int value = (int)((int)(getName().charAt(0)) * 1.1);
// --------------------------------------------^
```

There, if `getName()` returns `"Centaur"` (for instance), the `C` has the Unicode value `67`, and `value` ends up being `73`.

Comment: My mistake, it actually told us to take the modulus, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the code you're calling the class with and that is generating your error message. Why is it expecting 0? 8 seems like a valid return value from the information you've given.